# allocating array of chars and printing first entry

Tags: c

when i run this i get segv on printf, what am i doing wrong?

```
int main() {
        char **bla;
        int size =10;
        int i;

        bla = calloc(size*size,sizeof(char *));

        for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
                *bla = calloc(10,sizeof(char));
                strncpy(*bla,"aaaaa",size);
                bla++;
        }

        printf("%s\n",bla[0]);
}
```

I know i could do this with

```
int main() {
        char **bla;
        int size =10;
        int i;

        bla = calloc(size*size,sizeof(char *));

        for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
                bla[i] = calloc(10,sizeof(char));
                strncpy(bla[i],"aaaaa",size);
        }



   printf("%s\n",bla[0]);
   }
```

but is there any way to do this with pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By writing `bla++`, you're changing `bla` to point to the next pointer.

At the end, `bla[0]` (which is equivalent to `*bla`) has been incremented 10 times and will point the memory location immediately after the allocated block.

You could fix this by writing `bla -= 10` after the loop.

However, the best way to fix it is to not increment `bla` at all, and instead write

```
 *(bla + i) = calloc(10,sizeof(char));
```

Alternatively, you could declare a second pointer (`char** currentBlah = blah`) and increment it instead, then print `blah[0]`, which will still point to the original memory location.

Comment: I second the recommendation to use a second pointer for traversing the array.  If you lose track of the value returned by `alloc`, you won't be able to `free` the memory later.  For best results, make a copy and don't touch the original pointer.

Comment: -1 `*(bla + i)` is just `bla[i]`, which is exactly what the OP was asking to avoid...

Comment: @Chris: I suspect not.  This is probably a homework assignment for pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your allocation loop uses `bla` to iterate through the array of pointers, so at the end of that loop, `bla` points to just after the end of the array rather than the beginning.  You need a loop like:

```
for (p=bla; p < bla+size; p++) { 
        *p = calloc(size, sizeof(char)); 
        strncpy(*p, "aaaaa", size); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the first case you've moved the bla pointer past the end of the array (the last bla++) so when you access the first you are actually accessing past the last